# Filter array in Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have an entity "PlayerStatisticsData" that has a field "transactions" containing another object "PlayerTransaction", which has a timestamp field. 
However, since that list can get really big, I only want to query recent objects.
How can I query PlayerStatisticsData, but with a transactions list that only contains PlayerTransaction objects which's timestamp are greater than a given value?

I hope this was clear to understand.
[image]

Comment: what exactly have you tried? Do you mean you want to filter the content in the DB, or in an existing Java Array or List?

Comment: I wanna filter the content within the query so it doesn't even get loaded in Java. I figured I can use the $filter aggregation, however I have no idea on how to use that in Morphia.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a project to define an array slice but that only lets you specify how many to return.  You can't introspect the values and filter out items like that.  So, e.g., you could ask mongo to return the first or last 50 (if they're already ordered) but you can't tell it to slice by, say, a date field on the array element's document.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/